# What is the cause of "Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory"?

Tags: linux, pip, virtualenv

I have a Python virtual environment on my linux machine. It has been working fine for two weeks, but all of a sudden I woke up today, and while in the environment I can't execute any commands. For example, if I try to use pip list, or jupyter notebook, this is what I get (env is the name of my environment):

```
~/env/bin$ pip list
-bash: /home/ubuntu/env/bin/pip: /home/ubuntu/env/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The same thing happens with basically any other command, except Python. Typing python brings up the Python shell just fine. Interestingly it says Anaconda though, when I only used pip with this environment.

I've tried to find info on this but they all seem to be pertaining to running scripts.

Edit: Also want to mention that when I manually look in the environment bin, the packages I installed are all there in green, except Python is in red.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your PATH variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a script `/home/ubuntu/env/bin/pip` and the script has [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/home/ubuntu/env/bin/python` but the file is either absent or is not executable.

Check if the file `/home/ubuntu/env/bin/python` exist. Check if it can be executed by the current user (just run it from the command line). If not — you need to find out a working executable (for example, it could be `/home/ubuntu/env/bin/python3`), edit the first line of `/home/ubuntu/env/bin/pip` to fix the shebang.