# Getting error "/usr/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" after installing pip in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I installed python3.9 in ubuntu and also make it default which creates some problems. So I again make python 3.5 as default and removed python 3.9.

Then I tried to install pip by using command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and it installed successfully but when I ran:

```
pip3 --version
```

it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why I removed python 3.9 completely with all its dependencies then why pip is not installing properly?

Please help me out here i'm really stuck.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.9? It does not come with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Use pyenv/pipenv/venvs to prevent messing around with system's Python interpreter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739657/7976758

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373253/16561060) might help, you can run `pip` as a module, try `python3 -m pip [commands]` to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
pip --version
```

It might work.